# LVM incorrectly reported missing after power failure

Tags: lvm, mdadm

We have had a major power failure in the data-center. We are using a set of servers for our storage needs. The main server has several pairs of disks mirrored with mdadm. The resulting /dev/mdX are LVM physical volumes and belong to a big volume-group with all our data.

After the powerloss, we had the problem that one of the mdadm devices was not auto-detected due to a missing entry in `mdadm.conf`. As a consequence, the volumegroup had inactive logical volumes due to the missing PV.

We were able to fix the mdadm config and reboot. `pvscan` shows all expected PVs but one LV still does not come up. vgdisplay shows:

```
[...]
Cur PV:  3
Act PV:  2
[...]
```

Neither vgscan nor pvscan show any missing devices.

What went wrong? How can we force LVM to activate all PVs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A fix we came up with in the hurry was to do:

```
vgcfgbackup -f backup.vg
```

Then edit the file, replacing

```
flags = ["MISSING"]
```

with

```
flags = []
```

In the PV that was the problem and used

```
vgcfgrestore -f backup_edited.vg
```

to load the modified config. After that, `vgchange -a y name_of_the_vg` worked like expected.

Comment: Thanks!! I applied this fix for a PV that mysteriously got the missing state and all fine.